# Firestore Data retrieval asynch update problem

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I've read now multiple threads on data retrieval from Firestore but I still haven't been able to find an answer and make this work -> making me open a new thread.

I'm trying to get the count of documents in a subcollection of a collection of Categories to display onto a detailTextlabel in Tableview. The data retrieval for the categories (Documents in a higher collection) works fine, getting the data asynchronously and displaying them at cellForRow level.

However, I'm trying to get it's subcollection querySnapshot?.count, which also then loads into a Dictionary as wished, but I can't get it do load the data outside of the closure (I can't get it to work with DispatchQueue.main.asynch). The second to last print statement (categories) works fine, the one below it, shows an empty dict.

I'd greatly appreciate any kind of input.

Thanks 
Ivo

Please find the code here:

```
func loadCategories() {

        if let currentUserEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {

            let docRef = db.collection(currentUserEmail).order(by: "Name")

            docRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents> \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        print(document.data())
                        self.categories.append(document.documentID)


                        self.db.collection(currentUserEmail).document(document.documentID)
                            .collection(document.documentID).whereField("Category", isEqualTo: document.documentID)
                            .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in

                                if let error = error {
                                    print("\(error)")
                                } else {

                                    if let docCount = querySnapshot?.count {
                                        self.categoryQuestionCountSub[document.documentID] = docCount
                                    }
                                    print("\(self.categoryQuestionCountSub) outside if let")
                                }
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }

                    }
                    print("\(self.categories) outside of Loop")
                    print("\(self.categoryQuestionCountSub) outside of Loop")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this - I figured out I just put the DispatchQueue blog into the wrong spot. Below you will find the adjusted code which works as intended.

```
func loadCategories() {

    if let currentUserEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {

        let docRef = db.collection(currentUserEmail).order(by: "Name")

        docRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents> \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print(document.data())
                    self.categories.append(document.documentID)


                    self.db.collection(currentUserEmail).document(document.documentID)
                        .collection(document.documentID).whereField("Category", isEqualTo: document.documentID)
                        .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in

                            if let error = error {
                                print("\(error)")
                            } else {

                                if let docCount = querySnapshot?.count {
                                    self.categoryQuestionCountSub[document.documentID] = docCount


                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```